# Powershell: Compare files and delete if exists

Tags: powershell

I do a backup every day of new modified/created files and I have a problem when I try to delete the files on the backup drive if they don't exist anymore in source. I have found couple ways of doing that but they don't work. I still have some leftovers that shouldn't be there.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$Item1=Get-ChildItem "E:\"
$Item2=Get-ChildItem "S:\E\"
$DifferenceItem=Compare-Object $Item1 $Item2  
$ItemToBeDeleted=$DifferenceItem | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq  "=>" }
foreach ($item in $ItemToBeDeleted)
{
    $FullPath=$item.InputObject.FullName
    Remove-Item $FullPath -Force -Recurse
}
```

```
$yourdir1="E:\"
$yourdir2="S:\E\"

$filesnamedir1=(gci -recurse $yourdir1).Name
gci -recurse $yourdir2 | where Name -notin $filesnamedir1| remove-item -recurse -force
```

Also first one only works in the target folder, doesn't go to subfolders.

I would be grateful if someone could help. Thank you.

**Edit:** Robocopy wont work for me because it doesn't have a switch to copy recently created files.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -recurse`...

Comment: this sounds like a classic use case for robocopy. plus, it is almost always far, far faster than anything PoSh can do since it is a dedicated util. plus plus, it can be run from inside a PoSh script. [*grin*]

Comment: @NekoMusume I guess it works. Thank you. Although I have started it about 10 min ago and its still working. 40 000 files in those folders. I guess I will need to find another way.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yeah, I used robocopy until I have decided to copy not only files that were modified recently but also created recently (copied from another PC, flash, internet, etc).

Comment: /mir Mirrors a directory tree (equivalent to /e plus /purge).

Comment: @Maredha - robocopy will copy any file that is in $Source but not in $Dest. it will also remove any file that is not in $Source but is in $Dest. take a look at >>> `/MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).` <<<

Comment: @RetiredGeek It wont work for me. I need to copy just the files that were created or modified recently. Thanks though.

Comment: @Maredha - robocopy also has MinAge & MaxAge options ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, but they refer to modified date, there is no switch for creation date. So if I download a file for example or copy it from outside of my PC it wont be included.

Comment: @Maredha - ah! that was not clear to me from reading your Question. you may want to update things with more detail about why robocopy is not working for you.

Comment: Roboform won't copy files that already exist on the destination with the same date-time.

Comment: That's why I added "backup every day of new **modified/created** files" in there. But no problem, I will add that. Thanks.